# Removing a key from a nested dictionary based on value

Tags: python

I previusly asked about adding, and someone helped me out with append. My new problem is trying to delete a key with a nested list, e.g.:

**JSON:**

```
data = {"result":[{"name":"Teddy","list":{"0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"}},
           {"name":"Barney","list":{"0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"}]}
```

**Python:**

```
name = input("Input a key to delete") #Must hold a value. 
data["result"].pop(name)
```

**E.g. Barney => then delete Barney etc.**

I use the method below to find a key, but I am not sure this is the correct approach. 
**Finding Barney:**

```
for key in data['result']:
   if key['name'] == name:
       print("Found!!!!")
```

I am not sure. This surely does not work, maybe I should loop through each key or? Any suggestion or code example is worth.

**After Delete:** Now that barney was deleted the dictionary remains like this.

```
data = {"result":[{"name":"Teddy","list":{"0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"}}]}
```

Comment: What is `name` here? Also, again keep in mind that it `data['result']` holds list. You need to `del` the value based on index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to remove list items from the JSON document, you'll want to:

- Convert the JSON document into a Python data structure
- Manipulate the Python data structure
- Convert the Python data structure back to a JSON document

Here is one such program:

```
import json

def delete_keys(json_string, name):
    data = json.loads(json_string)
    data['result'][:] = [d for d in data['result'] if d.get('name') != name]
    json_string = json.dumps(data)
    return json_string

j = '''
    {"result":[{"name":"Teddy",
                "list":{"0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"}},
               {"name":"Barney","list":{"0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"}}]}'''
print delete_keys(j, 'Barney')
```

Result:

```
$ python x.py 
{"result": [{"list": {"1": "43", "0": "24", "2": "56"}, "name": "Teddy"}]}
```

Note this list comprehension:

```
data['result'][:] = [d for d in data['result'] if d.get('name') != name]
```

The form `l[:] = [item in l if ...]` is one way to delete several items from a list according to the indicated condition.

Comment: @haxxir411 That's not at all clear from your question. But if all that you need is the "how-to-modify-the-Python-object", I have highlighted that line for you.

Comment: I had the condition wrong. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the JSON into a JavaScript object.

```
var resultString = '{'result':[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value3','key2':'value4'}]}';
var result = JSON.parse(resultString);
```

Once you do, you should be more aware that this is an array of objects. You need to know which index you want to remove. You can use the .find method for arrays

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

if you don't know the index.

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries)); 
// { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

Realize though that find does not work in IE. Once you know the index, you can split the array.

```
var myFish = ["angel", "clown", "drum", "mandarin", "surgeon"];
var removed = myFish.splice(3, 1);

// removed is ["mandarin"]
// myFish is ["angel", "clown", "drum", "surgeon"]
```

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: I am coding in Python!

Answer (score 0):

Since `data['result']` is a `list`, you'll have to go to the index and delete the key. If you're looking to delete the key across all indices in the `list`, you could quickly write a function that iterates through the list and deletes the matching key

```
def delete_key(list_obj, key):
    for value in list_obj:
        if key in value:
            value.pop(key)
    return list_obj

result = delete_key(data["result"], 'key1')
```