# Deleting a key from a nested dictionary / json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to remove an element from a JSON file using python. I have converted the dictionary to a python dictionary and so far I have been failing. [JSON file I am working with is uploaded here](https://pastebin.com/7RVSRJtw)

I need to delete all the associated keys and value from the JSON if the key is `'access_ip_v4'`.

I cannot use sed/grep or any other regex techniques or string replace techniques. I am kind of stuck with python dictionaries on this.

Here is my work so far.

```
def dict_sweep(input_dic, k):
    for key in input_dic.keys():
        if key == k:
            print("DIRECT DELETE")
            del input_dic[key]
        elif type(input_dic[key]) is dict:
            print('DICT FOUND')
            input_dic[key] = dict_sweep(input_dic[key], k)
        elif isinstance(type(input_dic[key]), type([])):
            print("LIST FOUND")
            for i, v in enumerate(input_dic[key]):
                if isinstance(input_dic[key][i], dict):
                    input_dic[key][i] = dict_sweep(v, k)
    return input_dic
```

I think my code fails when it encounters a list. Failing in the sense,

```
clean_data = dict_sweep(data, 'access_ip_v4')
print(clean_data)
```

will again print the `data` rather than printing the cleaned version of data.

I am not so sure about it. I have read some other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267926/removing-a-key-from-a-nested-dictionary-based-on-value) but It is not helpful. Can someone give me a pointer here?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by fail? Also, type([]) is called list

Comment: I have updated the question. It is not giving me the cleaned version of the data after removing the key `access_ip_v4`.

Comment: I recommend you update you question to indicate you are using Python3 as the RuntimeError you are getting is specific to PYthon3 in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The error

Your error comes from the expression `isinstance(type(input_dic[key]), type([]))`. You want to check if `input_dict[key]` is a list, not `type(input_dic[key])` which is a type.

So replace the last `elif` statement by this.

```
elif isinstance(input_dic[key], list):
    print("LIST FOUND")
    ...
```

## A better approach

Although, it is not recommended to delete from the object you are iterating over. In particular, if you are using Python3, the above code will raise `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. The correct approach is to build a new dictionary without the keys you want to delete.

```
def dict_sweep(input_dict, key):
    if isinstance(input_dict, dict):
        return {k: dict_sweep(v, key) for k, v in input_dict.items() if k != key}

    elif isinstance(input_dict, list):
        return [dict_sweep(element, key) for element in input_dict]

    else:
        return input_dict
```

Here is the result.

```
d = {'delete': 1, 'ok': [{'delete': 1, 'ok': 1}]}
new_d = dict_sweep(d, 'delete') # {'ok': [{'ok': 1}]}
```

Comment: Kudos for your effort and explanation. This works without any issues.